# JQuery style and Ajax not work properly on new host

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

After moving to VPS server this code not apply **jQuery** style, just not formatted dropdown autocomplete list... autocomplete shows all selected values in non-formated style, but at the same time show alert 'No search results'

Please advise what is the possible reason that this code stop works properly

```
<?php
require_once ("pg_conn.php");
$array[]="";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
$(function() {          
    $('#street').autocomplete({
        source: 'street.php'                     
    });
}); 

function sendForm(form){
    form.submit();
}           
</script>     
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <form method="get" action="acmp.php" >      
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="street">Street:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Street name" required="required" 
                    id="street" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace http with https:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved